# How to play a video splash in ios?(Objective c)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I need a help in how to implement the video splash while my application launches in ios.
The sample which is similar to:
http://www.iosappx.com/code/9173/

Answer (score 1):

You could have a "fake" launch video. So, if you have a local video file(mp4 or other supported formats), you could set the window rootViewController to AVPlayerViewController. Example as below:

Within your AppDelegate.m file,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:"YOUR URL"];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(continueWithLaunch) name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:player];
// create a player view controller
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = controller;
controller.player = player;
[player play];
}  

-(void) continueWithLaunch {
  //Change the window rootView controller to your base controller (e.g. tabbar controller)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible: right now, the only "splash" (i.e., launch) screens you can implement for iOS are either:

1. Static images (the historic Default*.png)
2. Single-page storyboards (Launchscreen.storyboard)

The app you linked to **seems to be just playing video on its first (login) screen, *after* the "splash"** (likely, backed by a view controller).

Comment: perhaps you could reformulate your question as "How can I play video in the background of my app's main view" or something similar.