# How to play video in fullscreen size in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I want to play some video in splash screen in portrait mode - full screen.
Is that possible? please guide me through a proper solution.

I'm looking for swift solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play a video splash in ios?(Objective c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515407/how-to-play-a-video-splash-in-iosobjective-c)

Comment: its in objective c

Comment: @Abhishek That link is ObjC, moreover the accepted answer is basically linking to a Github repo...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create a subclass of `UIView`, with a `AVPlayer` and a function `createBackground`:

```
import AVFoundation

class BackgroundVideo: UIView {
  var player: AVPlayer?

  func createBackground(name: String, type: String) { }
}
```

then your `createBackground` might be something like:

```
func createBackground(name: String, type: String) {
  guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type) else { return }
    
  player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
  player?.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none
  let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
  playerLayer.frame = self.frame
  playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
  self.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)
  player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
  player?.play()
}
```

then you may add more stuff, such as observing notifications:

- `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` for implementing a video loop.
- `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` for controlling the video loop, after resuming from background.

finally you might attach this `BackgroundView`, wherever you need: fake splash screen, home screen, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 3.0**

You can not do that in default splash screen but you can do some workaround to acheive this.

First of all you should take first frame of your video which will be image.

You can do that using photoshop or by any other graphics tool.

Now you can set it to you default splash screen in UIImageView.

Now make a UIViewController and launch that as initial view controller.

And below is the code to play video

```
    private func playFullScreenVideo() {
    // drag your video file in  project
    // check if video file is available,if not return
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"mp4") else {
        debugPrint("video.mp4 missing")
        return
    }
    // create instance of videoPlayer with video path
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    // create instance of playerlayer with videoPlayer
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
    // set its videoGravity to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill to make it full size
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    // add it to your view
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    playerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    // start playing video
    videoPlayer?.play()
  }
```

Let me know if having any trouble in this

Answer (score 0):

Inside  didFinishLaunch method of app delegate

```
let splashScreenVC = viewController(withIdentifier: "identifier", inStoryboard: "storyboard:) as? SplashViewController
window?.rootViewController = splashScreenVC
```

Inside the view controller SplashViewController, you can play video in viewDidLoad method.

```
 func playVideo() {
    guard let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Redtaxi-splash", ofType:"mov") else {
        return
    }

    let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController?.player = player
    playerViewController?.showsPlaybackControls = false
    playerViewController?.view.frame = view.frame
    playerViewController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
    playerViewController?.view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)

    view.addSubview((playerViewController?.view)!)
    playerViewController?.player?.play()
}
```